# How to run a function defined on a jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-plugins

I have searched for 3 days the web to find a solution to my simple problem.
I try to run the `pause` function in a external `<a>` tag from this script: http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/js/jquery.galleriffic.js

```
pause: function() {
            this.isSlideshowRunning = false;
            if (this.slideshowTimeout) {
                clearTimeout(this.slideshowTimeout);
                this.slideshowTimeout = undefined;
            }
```

I tried something like this: `<a href="javascript:fn.galleriffic.extend.pause()">pause</a>`

edit: whole script:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/galleriffic-2.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.galleriffic.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.opacityrollover.js"></script>
    <!-- We only want the thunbnails to display when javascript is disabled -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write('<style>.noscript { display: none; }</style>');
    </script>
</head>
<body>
            <!-- Start Advanced Gallery Html Containers -->
            <div id="gallery" class="content">
                <div id="controls" class="controls"></div>
                <div class="slideshow-container">
                    <div id="loading" class="loader"></div>
                    <div id="slideshow" class="slideshow"></div>
                </div>
                <a id="sstop" href="#">pause</a> <!--here the link-->
                <div id="caption" class="caption-container"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="thumbs" class="navigation">
                <ul class="thumbs noscript">
                    <li>
                ...
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var galleryswtch=0;
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            // We only want these styles applied when javascript is enabled
            $('div.navigation').css({'width' : '300px', 'float' : 'left'});
            //$('div.content').css('display', 'none');

            // Initially set opacity on thumbs and add
            // additional styling for hover effect on thumbs
            var onMouseOutOpacity = 0.67;
            $('#thumbs ul.thumbs li').opacityrollover({
                mouseOutOpacity:   onMouseOutOpacity,
                mouseOverOpacity:  1.0,
                fadeSpeed:         'fast',
                exemptionSelector: '.selected'
            });

            // Initialize Advanced Galleriffic Gallery
            var gallery = $('#thumbs').galleriffic({
                delay:                     2500,
                numThumbs:                 3,
                preloadAhead:              10,
                enableBottomPager:         true,
                maxPagesToShow:            11,
                imageContainerSel:         '#slideshow',
                controlsContainerSel:      '#controls',
                captionContainerSel:       '#caption',
                loadingContainerSel:       '#loading',
                renderSSControls:          true,
                renderNavControls:         true,
                playLinkText:              'Play Slideshow',
                pauseLinkText:             'Pause Slideshow',
                prevLinkText:              '&lsaquo; Previous Photo',
                nextLinkText:              'Next Photo &rsaquo;',
                nextPageLinkText:          'Next &rsaquo;',
                prevPageLinkText:          '&lsaquo; Prev',
                enableHistory:             false,
                autoStart:                 false,
                syncTransitions:           true,
                defaultTransitionDuration: 900,
                onSlideChange:             function(prevIndex, nextIndex) {
                    // 'this' refers to the gallery, which is an extension of $('#thumbs')
                    this.find('ul.thumbs').children()
                        .eq(prevIndex).fadeTo('fast', onMouseOutOpacity).end()
                        .eq(nextIndex).fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
                },
                onPageTransitionOut:       function(callback) {
                    this.animate({opacity: '0'}, 500, 'linear', callback);

                },
                onPageTransitionIn:        function() {
                    this.animate({opacity: '1'}, 500, 'linear');
                }
            });

            $('#sstop').click(function() {$('#gallery').galleriffic('pause');}); //here the js
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Galleriffic is a jQuery extension that acts on DOM elements it should be:

```
$(myselector).galleriffic("pause");
```

where `myselector` is a reference to whichever element has had the gallery attached to it [e.g. `'#thumbs'` if you're using the same element IDs as in the Galleriffic examples.]

Ideally, make this association in your JS files rather than doing it inline in the HTML by first giving your link and ID:

```
<a href="#" id="pause_link"> Pause </a>
```

and then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // do all of the rest of your galleriffic setup
    $('#thumbs').galleriffic(
        // initial options
    );

    // and then link the pause link with the gallery
    $('#pause_link').click(function() {
        $('#thumbs').galleriffic('pause');
    });
});
```

[rationale - in modern HTML putting your Javascript inline is considered "olde worlde"]

Comment: would the downvoter please care to explain?  AFAIK (and I've done a _lot_ of jQuery programming) this _is_ the right answer!

Comment: yes this this definitiv the right answer. but how must i write it exatctly? sorry about this question i'm a js learner.

Comment: You can assign a regular old javascript variable (say, var gallery) to the instance of the gallery (as they do on the main sample page for this gallery).  Then you can access its pause method.  There is no need to go through the effort of finding the object using jquery.  But it wasn't me that downvoted.

Comment: @Alnitak I've noticed (and been the victim of) some very odd down voting in the last few days. May be time to start a thread on meta about it.

Comment: @James in that sample what you get is a jQuery object - you can't call the individual widget's methods without dispatching back through the main `.galleriffic()` function.

Comment: @ Alnitak i just tried your example but firebug tell me: imageData is undefined [Bei diesem Fehler anhalten/ stop at this error] var index = imageData.index;

Comment: @p.oner you're somehow triggering an error inside galleriffic, but that at least shows that you are now actually _calling_ `pause()` OK! :)  Finding the cause of that error is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: ah - I see you posted your code.  You've used the wrong ID when you called `.galleriffic('pause')`.  It should be `#thumbs`, not `#gallery`.

Comment: yes thanks a lot :) i can call the pause function, but the slide show won't stop. have you as a "lot of jquery coder" an hint how i can stop the slide show with the <a id="sstop"...?

Comment: @Alnitak they do exactly what I'm talking about on this page http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/example-4.html - assign a js var to `$(thing).galleriffic({})` and then call galleriffic methods using that.

Comment: @James odd - that doesn't usually work - it looks like they haven't used the usual widget pattern.  The OP _may_ need to call `$('#thumbs').galleriffic.pause()`, or maybe even just `$('#thumbs').pause()`.

Comment: okay thank you for this hint :) you save my day. i write for the solution: $('#sstop').click(function(e) {gallery.pause(); e.preventDefault();});

thank you

Answer (score 0):

To invoke a function with no parameters (such as this one), you should call it like `pause()`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
yourobjectname.pause();
```

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why

```
$('#myElement').delay(2000)
```

wont work?
or is it pausing for undefined time?

if so just make a new function and call it on your a.click event :)

Comment: it's a gallery slideshow widget - its `pause` method _stops_ the slideshow - it's completely unrelated to `.delay`.